why the css not linked to the index.html
I'm working on making "is it newyear page" and the page should answer with yes or no, this is not the problem but the problem here is with the link i wrote this link inside of the <head' which is <link href= "{% static 'newyear/styles.css'%} rel="stylesheet" and i run the server but nothing from my style applied to the page so I'm trying to figureout what is the problem
some details:
the app name is newyear
i have a folder inside of it called static/newyear
and the styles.css file inside of the newyear folder
i did not try anything to solve it because there is only this way to link
i just deleted the link and tried it many times but still not working
the codes:
{% load static %}
<Doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <title>Is it New Year?</title>
       <link href="{% static 'newyear/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    </head> 
    
    <body>
        {% if newyear %}
           <h1>YES!</h1>
        {% else %}
           <h1> NO!!!</h1>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>    







Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. [edit] the question and include code fragments with the code sample button ({}).

Aside: make sure to use a proper doctype.

IF you write "on server", and it is not the localhost, i think, probably you need to apply the collectstatic django cli.
More here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/
